# MYSQL - Retrieving Only Full Words From Tag Search

Tags: php, mysql, regex, database

I am trying to retrieve entries from mysql database where the keywords in the database correspond to either the title of an article, or the tags for an article. At the moment I am using instr, but this isn't specific enough because I have found that too many irrelevant results are retrieved for shorter keywords - ie. I try to retrieve entries where the title or tags list has the word 'art' but it ends up retrieving other entries with words like 'article'.

I have the following table structure. The database has a predefined list of tags. Each article category is assigned a number of tags from the main tag list:

```
tags_tbl (overall tags list)

    tt_tag_id (pk) int

    tt_tag  varchar

category_tag_assignments_tbl (the category which a tag is assigned to)

    cta_id (pk) int

    cta_tag_for_id (fk to tags_tbl.tt_tag_id) int

    cat_for_id (fk to category table) int
```

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM tags_tbl INNER JOIN category_tag_assignments_tbl ON tags_tbl.tt_tag_id = category_tag_assignments_tbl.cta_tag_for_id WHERE instr('The Article Title' , tags_tbl.tt_tag) > 0 OR instr('these,are,article,tags' , tags_tbl.tt_tag) > 0
```

How can I make it so that I can search both within the article title, and within the article tags, for a full word, without retrieving longer words where the string also might appear, whilst also taking into account the fact that the tags list is delimited by a comma without spaces? I want to minimize the amount of php processing - I have no control over the actual presentation of the titles and tags, since these are provided by an external source, unless I modify them with php ahead of time.

I am thinking of incorporating the following regex, which I found here on stackoverflow, but I don't know how to apply it in this case because I am searching within my search terms (sorry clumsy wording I know, but I can't think of how else to say it):

```
WHERE tags_tbl.tt_tag REGEXP '[[:<:]]art[[:>:]]'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you could consider full text search in boolean mode.  This would probably perform better than any string-based solution.

That said, you can do what you want by surrounding the tag and search string with delimiters:

```
SELECT *
FROM tags_tbl INNER JOIN
     category_tag_assignments_tbl
     ON tags_tbl.tt_tag_id = category_tag_assignments_tbl.cta_tag_for_id
WHERE concat(' ', 'The Article Title', ' ') like concat('%', tags_tbl.tt_tag, '%')OR
      concat(',', 'these,are,article,tags', ',') like concat('%', tags_tbl.tt_tag, '%')
```

The last expression can actually be simplified by using `find_in_set()`, for the following `where` clause:

```
WHERE concat(' ', 'The Article Title', ' ') like concat('%', tags_tbl.tt_tag, '%')OR
      find_in_set(tags_tbl.tt_tag, 'these,are,article,tags') > 0
```

You could actually use it for the first expression too -- which can be handy if there are commas in the title:

```
WHERE find_in_set(tags_tbl.tt_tag, replace('The Article Title', ' ', ',') or
      find_in_set(tags_tbl.tt_tag, 'these,are,article,tags') > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff. The concat thing works as I would like it to. Thank you. I will also look more at boolean mode. Thanks!